# Is it possible to get isinstance or similar type-checking to work with my pickled classes?

Tags: python, class, pickle, typechecking, isinstance

I have a really annoying bug, and I've finally tracked it down.

I use (or more accurately, already have used) a stand-alone script to create a store of objects, after which I pickle this data structure. I can then initialize my main program with the deserialized data each time my program runs.

This becomes a problem, however, if I use type-checking. After I do pickle.dump() and get this data structure, I had it set up so that I try to check the type of one the objects. Unfortunately, the only thing I can check it against is a *new* reloading of my classes, which Python recognizes as distinct.

> DEBUG: Object I am type-checking: >> Fixture {name: 'Front Desk', location: '0', desc: 'The front desk has a sign that read...'} <<
>   DEBUG: A generic GameObject: >> GameObject {name: '', location: 'None', desc: '...' } <<

(You can see that the object representations look very similar. This is because the one inherits its `__repr__` from the other, i.e. OUGHT to be an instance of it.)

> DEBUG: Type of object I am type-checking: {class 'chimai.chimai.objects.fix.Fixture'}
>   DEBUG: Type of generic GameObject: {class 'objects.game_object.GameObject'}
>   DEBUG: MRO for the object I'm type-checking: ({class 'chimai.chimai.objects.fix.Fixture'}, {class 'chimai.chimai.objects.game_object.GameObject'}, {type 'object'})
>   DEBUG: MRO for the generic GameObject: ({class 'objects.game_object.GameObject'}, {type 'object'})

(The GameObject classes have slightly different identifiers; this comes from where I ran the standalone script originally.)

> DEBUG: Id of pickled Fixture type: 173671604
>   DEBUG: Id of Fixture type as reloaded in my main program: 149507748

The end result is, I can't think of a way to type-check my pickled data at all. Unless anyone has any genius proposals, I think I'll be duck-typing.

Comment: Yuo are not checking the same object *at all*. You are comparing a `fix.Fixture` instance with a `game_object.GameObject`. Clearly those are not the same type of object. I think you are misunderstanding what your code does, this has *nothing* to do with Pickle.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. `isinstance()`, given an instance of `fix.Fixture` and the class `game_object.GameObject` returned `False`. This is why I investigated these two.

Comment: And is `fix.Fixture` supposed to be a subclass of `game_object.GameObject`?

Comment: Look at the MROs I just posted. `fix.Fixture` is indeed a direct subclass of `game_object.GameObject`. However, THAT particular `fix.Fixture` instance is a subclass of a different `game_object.GameObject` than the one I compared it to.  

See, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620844/why-do-i-get-unexpected-behavior-in-python-isinstance-after-pickling?rq=1
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876395/isinstance-behavior-with-module-reload

Comment: It's a result of the fact that in pickling in one session and using the data in other, you effectively have load the class two different times, which creates a different object each.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/620866/1151229

Comment: Then this question is a dupe of [Why do I get unexpected behavior in Python isinstance after pickling?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/620844) and `game_object.GameObject` was *replaced*. This is not a problem limited to pickle.

Comment: The post you link to is about *the same session*, btw. This does *not happen* when pickling in one session, then starting a new python script and unpickling again.

Comment: Is it? Well, what about the other links I posted?

Comment: Those are *all* in the same Python session.

Comment: Again, I don't think the session is really what matters. It's the reloading of the class that causes isinstance to not work as expected. 

Like in this example, I don't if I already linked to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877454/1151229

Comment: That is what I am saying. If your code is reloading the modules somewhere, then yes, you'll have that exact same problem. But why post a *new question* in that case? Then this is just a dupe. Your question and answer implies that you are creating a new session and that that is the root of the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28656/discussion-between-bepetersn-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible in any simple way; type-checking is incompatible with data pickled in a different session. I'm not a zealot when it comes to type-checking, but I like what works.

Comment: Pickle should give you the *same type*; it uses the same class reference (module -> class definition) as the original. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: A class is an object. When you reload a module, in a different session, you create a different class object. See, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/620866/1151229

Comment: If by different session you mean a new interpreter, than *your diagnosis is wrong*. In that new session `pickle` will use the same classes to unpickle as what you are using to test for `isinstance()`. Unless in that new session the classes have been swapped in the meantime.

Comment: I don't really know that the session (specifically the interepreter) has anything directly to do with it, actually. I just wanted to stress the fact of a different session because my particular use case for pickling necessarily involves loading the class once, in one script, and then loading it again later in another.

Comment: Sorry, but your diagnosis is still wrong. Make a simple test case. Create two classes in a module, one inheriting from the other. Test that `isinstance()` works. Then pickle these, and load them again in a new Python interpreter session. Test the isintance test again. **it will work**.